# PyQt4 OSX Wrong architecture

Tags: python, macos, pyqt

After installing PyQt using brew install, like so:

```
brew install qt
brew install sip
brew install pyqt
```

I try to run a sript and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exampleosx.py", line 17, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtGui
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtGui.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtGui.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

I've tried following many tutorials on how to run the code with different options but with no luck.

Adding "arch -i368" is not fixing the problem either.

I'm using OSX 10.7.5 and Python 2.7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running your script with this prefix.

```
VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=no /usr/bin/python exampleosx.py
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately I fixed the problem and not sure how/when. If I run into it again I will try this one for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your script with $arch -i386 in front on the command line, something like :

```
$arch -i386 python myscript.py
```

Because Pyqt is available for 32 bits architecture only.

Comment: Perhaps you must also do a "python configure.py -d /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages -b /usr/local/bin --use-arch=i386" as explained in this blog : http://amjith.blogspot.fr/2010/09/developing-pyqt4-applications-in-mac-os.html

Comment: I have no configure.py installing from brew, so I'll should try to install it from other source maybe, but it seems very weird to have a brew package that is not installing as expected.

Comment: Yes you're right, even QT only is not so easy to install. PyQT seems even worse. Sorry I cannot help you more. Good Luck !